# meaning of 'price out something'

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [a *TIME* article](https://time.com/6158182/vitalik-buterin-ethereum-profile/).

> “With fees being the way they are today,” Buterin says, “it really
> gets to the point where the financial derivatives and the gambley
> stuff start **pricing out** some of the cool stuff.”

I wonder what 'price out something' means.

My sense is that it means 'to exceed the price of something'.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notion is when you are forced out of a market, because you competors are selling a similar product at a lower price.

> Cheap clones made by Dell and other manufacturers priced out the original IBM PC.

It means that the IBM PC didn't sell well, because the clones were cheaper.

So in your example, it seems that "financial derivatives and the gambley stuff" are cheaper than "cool stuff" and so the cool stuff isn't selling well.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

'Price out' can be used a few different ways, in different contexts. In this context, it means ***to price out of the market***. That is when the price that one business charges is so different from its competitors that the market is no longer competitive. The loser in the competition is the one that is 'priced out'.

In your specific example, it seems that the "financial derivatives and the gambley stuff" are cheaper than the "cool stuff", which means the public are more likely to put their money into the inferior options. The 'cool stuff' is therefore priced out of the market, even though it might be a better option/product.

Comment: Thank you very much.